# Spring transaction config - XML + annotations together - which is senior?

Tags: spring, transactions

Suppose I have a Spring bean which has been marked with `@Transactional` at either class or method level, and I also have, in some Spring XML which uses `<aop:config>` to add transactional advice.

I think that both configurations can play nicely together, but when Spring creates its context and the proxies, in the event that the configurations are not compatible (eg. PROPAGATION_MANDATORY vs PROPAGATION_NEVER), then which config has seniority?

Comment: Possible dupe of  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991144/annotation-based-and-xml-based-transaction-definitions-precedence but it needs checking for Spring 3.0+

Comment: Thanks for this. That other question does indeed contain the answer I was after!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make explicit the answer from the duplicate question, you use:

```
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" order="X"/>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="txManager">

    <aop:config>
            <aop:pointcut id="pointcut" expression="..."/>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="pointcut" order="Y"/>
    </aop:config>
```

... where the **lower** of 'X' and 'Y' has priority.

[Spring Docs on the subject](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering)